# Vinogradov-Korobov prime number theorem error term (in English)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, analytic-number-theory

Vinogradov and Korobov independently proved in 1958 that 
$$\pi(x)=\text{Li}(x)+O\left(x\exp\left(-A\frac{(\log x)^{3/5}}{(\log\log x)^{1/5}}\right)\right),$$
for some positive constant $A$. Both of their original papers are in Russian and Davenport referenced a German book. Is there an exposition of this result in English?

Comment: In most [textbooks](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main5.pdf) it is proven with $\alpha > 0$ instead of $3/5$ (usually $\alpha = 1/10$), improving to $\alpha = 3/5$ makes the proof longer, but the method is globally the same thus the language of the paper isn't so important.

Comment: I have already looked at the very text you linked. What I am looking for is their treatment of exponential sums to obtain the zero-free region.

Comment: The Vinogradov method to bound $\zeta,\zeta'$ is in Titchmarsh's book.